# Copy the largest file among the range of log files within a given interval of time using shell/bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have created a code to copy all the files present in `/logpath` which are within the time range and contain `$string` in them. I would like to copy only the largest file among them instead of all the files.

```
find /logpath -type f -newermt "$Start-Time" ! -newermt "$End_Time" -exec grep -l $string {} + | xargs -i cp {} /destination
```

Comment: See https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-find-largest-file-in-directory-recursively-using-find-du/

Comment: Welcome, you should take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I tried changing the code to find /logpath -type f -newermt "$Start-Time" ! -newermt "$End_Time" -exec grep -l $string | sort -nr | head -1 |  {} + | xargs -i cp {} /destination.

But it is giving an error: -bash: {}: command not found
find: missing argument to `-exec'

Comment: Please add your comment into the question, with code formatting.  It is hard to read in comments.  One thing I see however, `-exec` must be ended with `\;`  And yoru `grep -l $string` does not specify what file to grep from, so it should be `grep -l $string {} \;`

Comment: Note that `{}` is only valid within the scope of the `find`. Once you pipe (`|`) to another command, `{}` does not mean anything.

Comment: *`find /logpath -type f -newermt "$Start-Time" ! -newermt "$End_Time" -exec grep -l $string`*  run just this much of your pipeline and look at the output. If you see multiple filenames (it seems that is your unstated question), then what common utility can you use to trim smaller files from the output? Good luck.

Comment: Can we add a condition so that only the largest list gets copied from the list?

Answer (score 0):

```
cp `find /logpath -type f -newermt "$Start-Time" ! -newermt "$End_Time" -exec grep -l $string {} \; | xargs ls -lS | head -1 | cut -d" " -f 9` /destination
```

I changed the approach slightly. The string of piped together commands inside the ` characters determines the full path of the file you want to copy, and that result is used as the first argument to the cp command.

Comment: This won't behave well if the resulting file has spaces in its name. Also see [ParsingLs](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and [BashFAQ #3: How can I sort or compare files based on some metadata attribute?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003)

Comment: (and spaces are just the easiest example of something that can throw this off; it's also legal for filenames to contain wildcard characters and even literal newlines)